# Consider the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = (y^{2} -y-2)(1-y)^{2}$ then find the values of $x$ for which the $y(x)$ is bounded below.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx} = (y^{2} -y-2)(1-y)^{2}$ then which option is true$?$

$a)$ if $y(0)= 0$, then $y$ is unbounded below.

$b)$ if $y(0)=3$ then $y$ is bounded below.

I solved the differential equation, and getting some complicated function in terms of $y$, I couldn't simplify the function in $y= f(x)$ form. So I am unable to solve this problem.

Any idea$?$

Comment: Do you have boundary conditions?

Comment: @Nick, I've edited the question.

Comment: What are the equilibrium points of this equation? This then already completely answers the questions, there is no need to compute an explicit solution.

Comment: @Moo, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is positive in $(-∞,-1)$ and $(2,∞)$ and it is negative in $(-1,2)$. So $y$ is increasing in $(-∞,-1)$ and $(2,∞)$ and decreasing in $(-1,2)$. Then how can I proceed$?$